# Pixel Lighting Shader

Tags: shaders, pixel-art

I'm making a material that is meant to pixelate only the lighting on an object while leaving the texture and geometry intact.

I'm currently having a problem where, when I plug in the node groups to pixelate the actual lighting, it oddly splits up the lighting of the individual blocks.

[image: Shader Setup]
[image: Node Group in Shader Setup:]

[image]
[image]

I've also noticed that this might be because of the Texter Coordinate node.

plugging in an Object seems to force every light to center on the origin of that object.
[image]
[image]

How do I make the pixelated lighting act like the normal lighting, without the odd separation between each block / reliance on a selected object?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to advice something when you don't share your node tree, but I can address this:

> plugging in an Object seems to force every light to center on the origin of that object.

Yes, the *Texture Coordinate: Object* gives you $xyz$ distances ("Translation") of currently processed point from the origin of the object specified in the option (current object if the field is empty). So one way to solve your problem is to select all objects and press <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *Apply Location*, to position all origins in the world origin. Otherwise you may want to offset the coordinate space by the location of the object:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Markus von Broady!

I completely forgot to add my node tree even though I had that there before I reformatted the question. I'll add it back lickity split!